# cd to directory with name of `-`

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to make a folder called `-`. I know it's a silly name, it's named so to mirror something else.

```
mkdir -
ls
> -
cd -
```

This makes it go up a folder or exit the symlink context depending on where I am. I found that `cd -` means [go to previous location](http://www.talug.org/events/20030813/cmdline_tips_n_tricks_aug03.html), but can't escape it. `cd \-` does not work.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use either relative or absolute paths to prevent the - from standing alone and confusing bash's build in command `cd`:

```
mkdir ./-
cd ./-
```

Comment: Nice. I realized after I posted I could go up a level and navigate back down two levels but your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Opposite to `~`, which gets evaluated by bash, `-` is an argument to `cd`. Have a look at the man pages (well, for current systems both are in `man bash` as `cd` is a builtin):

> ```
>    cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
>           Change the current directory to dir. [...]  An argument of - is equivalent
>           to $OLDPWD. [...]
> ```

And the paragraph on tilde expansion (simplified to the most common meaning):

> ```
> Tilde Expansion
>    If  a  word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), [...] the tilde-prefix 
>    is replaced with the home  directory associated with the specified login name.
> ```

`~` will be replaced by bash before passing the argument to the actual command. Thus, escaping it somehow (for example using `'~'` or `\~`) will work. `-` on the other hand will be passed to the command. Escaping has no use: bash will not evaluate it anyway, but it will get passed unescaped as single string to `cd`, which will subsequently open `$OLDPWD`.

---

A more esoteric alternative to Patrix' more reasonable way to open `-`-folders would be to set `$OLDPATH` to `-`:

```
OLDPATH=- cd -
```

Comment: I like the esoteric alternative :-)